# CSS grid middle row not changing size or moving

Tags: html, css

This is my first attemp to the css grid after watching some tutorials but im having a issue with position with my row grid. First i want to fill up the header div with a background but box of div features is overlapping. i add a border color so that i can see what the behavior of the grid. I tried to change px of middle grid in the grid-template-rows but it's not changing or moving.

```css
body {
  font-family: "inter", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:3px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 1fr 80px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h"
    "feat"
    "foot";
}
.header {
  grid-area: h;
  border: 1px solid rgb(199, 31, 31);
  background: green;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495474472287-4d71bcdd2085?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80");
}

.features {
  grid-area: feat;
  border: 1px solid rgb(16, 192, 68);
}

.footer {
  grid-area: foot;
  border: 1px solid rgb(165, 22, 146);
}

.header,
.features,
.footer {
  padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hero-content img {
  width: 300px;
}

.hero-content{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/84d2ebe131.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <title>Coffee Shop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Location</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="logo">
              <a href="#">Logo</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="features">
          <section class="hero-content">
            <figure>
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643552469055-00f36a16def4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
                alt=""
                style="border-radius: 50%"
              />
              <figcaption>Fresh Baked Bread</figcaption>
            </figure>

            <figure>
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514664902876-824dfe29bb64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
                alt=""
                style="border-radius: 50%"
              />
              <figcaption>Home Roasted Coffee</figcaption>
            </figure>

            <figure>
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591538519435-4578c3ba26d6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=923&q=80"
                alt="" style="border-radius: 50%;"
              />
              <figcaption>Good Market?</figcaption>
            </figure>
          </section>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
          <footer>
            123 Main Street Edwardsville, IL • 555-555-5555 • us@me.com
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
body {
  font-family: "inter", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:3px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 1fr 80px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h"
    "feat"
    "foot";
}
.header {
  grid-area: h;
  border: 1px solid rgb(199, 31, 31);
  background: green;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495474472287-4d71bcdd2085?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80");
}

.features {
  grid-area: feat;
  border: 1px solid rgb(16, 192, 68);
}

.footer {
  grid-area: foot;
  border: 1px solid rgb(165, 22, 146);
}

.header,
.features,
.footer {
  padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hero-content img {
  width: 300px;
}

.hero-content{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/84d2ebe131.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <title>Coffee Shop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <nav class="header">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Location</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="logo">
              <a href="#">Logo</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="features">
          <section class="hero-content">
            <figure>
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643552469055-00f36a16def4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
                alt=""
                style="border-radius: 50%"
              />
              <figcaption>Fresh Baked Bread</figcaption>
            </figure>

            <figure>
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514664902876-824dfe29bb64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
                alt=""
                style="border-radius: 50%"
              />
              <figcaption>Home Roasted Coffee</figcaption>
            </figure>

            <figure>
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591538519435-4578c3ba26d6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=923&q=80"
                alt="" style="border-radius: 50%;"
              />
              <figcaption>Good Market?</figcaption>
            </figure>
          </section>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
          <footer>
            123 Main Street Edwardsville, IL • 555-555-5555 • us@me.com
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If so, `class="header"` has been misplaced.